# Is 直感的 a noun or adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns

I'm a bit confused why jisho.org marks the word 直感的 as a noun in a sentence (直感的な人) while it's a Na-adjective in the dictionary. Based on the meaning and translation (intuitive person) it's also supposed to be an adjective. Is there a rule I don't know about or is it incorrectly marked as a noun?

[image]

Comment: I cannot find any instance of Jisho.org labeling 直観的【ちょっかんてき】 as a noun.  Can you edit your post to add a link showing this?  The actual 直観的【ちょっかんてき】 entry [here](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%9B%B4%E6%84%9F%E7%9A%84) clearly labels the word as a _"Na-adjective"_.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi as shown in the image above, you have to search for it in a phrase or sentence. Then you have to hover over it with your mouse and it shows a part of speech for each word you are hovering over. Though to me, this seems like a question for the creator of Jisho more than anything.

Comment: @Leebo -- Mousing over **Links** as shown in the screenshot, I get a popup menu, including [**Sentence search for 直観的**](https://jisho.org/search/直感的%20%23sentences).  However, I get no search results, so there's nothing to mouse over.  Since I couldn't reproduce the issue, I couldn't say much about how to proceed.

Comment: @Leebo -- However, if I search specifically for [直観的な人](https://jisho.org/search/直観的な人) and not just in "sentences", I can reproduce the OP's issue.  It seems that Jisho.org has this same mistake for all _-na_ adjectives formed from `[NOUN]` + 的, such as [印象的](https://jisho.org/search/印象的な人), [合理的](https://jisho.org/search/合理的な人), etc, but not for "regular" _-na_ adjectives like  [綺麗](https://jisho.org/search/綺麗な人).

Comment: @number, as Leebo suggested in the comment above, this is a mistake in the coding or data at Jisho.org, and should be reported to them directly.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi hmm, I was able to reproduce it without any issues. I searched for 直感的な人 in the main search bar, and when it shows up at the top, broken up by word as in the image, I moused over the word. It showed noun as mentioned. I didn't try searching in the sentences or anything.

Comment: @Leebo, yes, if you search for 直観的な人 in the main search bar, you get the results similar to the OP's.  If you just search for 直観的, you get different results that do not show incorrect information -- what I did initially, since I misunderstood the screenshot as showing the entry for 直観的.  If you use "sentence search" to search for 直観的, 直観的な人, or indeed, any string, you get no hits.

Answer (score 4):

The adjective you asked about is formed from the noun 直感｛ちょっかん｝ in the standard way of adding the 的{てき} suffix. Adjectives formed this way are all な-adjectives.

In the example you give (直感的な人), indeed, it seems to figure as a な-adjective qualifying 人.

You can also form an adverb from it in the standard way of adding に, as for all な-adjectives. Take for instance this sentence (from Tatoeba): 直感的{ちょっかんてき｝には、基本的な意味の最小単位は単語です。

Most な-adjective can also be used as nouns. However with adjectives formed using 的、usually you go back to the corresponding noun by simply removing 的.

For example: あなたは直感を信じないのですか？ "Do you believe in intuition?"
There would be no need to add 的 here.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Very helpful.